# After upgrade Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 Control Center no longer opens and Appearance no longer available

Tags: upgrade, mate, ubuntu-mate, appearance

Least technical post you may find.

Upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04.
Control center now fails to open even though it shows as being installed and up-to-date.  Therefore I can't change my appearance or other related operations.

Spent 2 weeks trying the different repairs found on-line for similar issues.
Decided to upgrade to 22.04 to see if that would fix the issue. Nope!

I keep track of my changes using GNOTE. In my list the is a line 'gnome-control-center'
this forces open the control center. However the layout is wrong and there is no 'Appearance' option.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. Please don't put the answer inside the question!

Comment: Upgrading never fixes problems it just carries them over.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow during upgrade(s) Control was given over to Gnome.

sudo apt install mate-control-center

returned control to Mate and all is correct now.

As an un-ranked amateur I have been the beneficiary of this communities
knowledge base many times.
I hope this helps someone out in return.